# Please find the issue my rock-paper-scissor code, getting same output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python. Tring to write a basic program on rock-paper-scissor using conditional if. but it give same output, Can anyone debug the issue?

```
print("....rock....")
print("....paper....")
print("....scissor....")

#enter your choice
player1=input("Player1 enter your choice:")
player2=input("Player2 enter your choice:")

print("Shoot!")

if player1!="" and player2!="":
    if (player2=="rock" and player1=="paper") or (player2=="scissor" and player1=="rock") or (player2=="paper" or player1=="scissor"):
        print("Player1 win!!")
    elif (player1=="rock" and player2=="paper") or (player1=="scissor" and player2=="rock") or (player1=="paper" or player2=="scissor"):
        print("Player2 win!!")
    elif player1==player2:
        print("it's draw")
    else:
        print("Something wrong")
else:
    print("Enter your choice correctly")
```

Getinng wrong output

```
python3 rock-paper-scissor-v1.py
....rock....
....paper....
....scissor....
Player1 enter your choice:rock
Player2 enter your choice:scissor
Shoot!
Player1 win!!


 python3 rock-paper-scissor-v1.py
....rock....
....paper....
....scissor....
Player1 enter your choice: scissor
Player2 enter your choice: rock
Shoot!
Player1 win!!
```

Comment: typo:  `(player2=="paper" or player1=="scissor"):` should be AND inside the parenthesis .. twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have error there instead of (player2=="paper" or player1=="scissor") it should be (player2=="paper" and player1=="scissor"). Also statement for Player2 also has this problem. Working code:

```
print("....rock....")
print("....paper....")
print("....scissor....")

#enter your choice
player1=input("Player1 enter your choice:")
player2=input("Player2 enter your choice:")

print("Shoot!")

if player1!="" and player2!="":
    if (player2=="rock" and player1=="paper") or (player2=="scissor" and player1=="rock") or (player2=="paper" and player1=="scissor"):
        print("Player1 win!!")
    elif (player1=="rock" and player2=="paper") or (player1=="scissor" and player2=="rock") or (player1=="paper" and player2=="scissor"):
        print("Player2 win!!")
    elif player1==player2:
        print("it's draw")
    else:
        print("Something wrong")
else:
    print("Enter your choice correctly")
```

Answer (score 0):

In both of your conditionals, the if and elif statements for the player choices, your last condition is an or statement thus if any of the two conditions is true, the whole expression becomes true.
So for your first statement and the first example

```
 if (player2=="rock" and player1=="paper") or (player2=="scissor" and player1=="rock") or (player2=="paper" or player1=="scissor"):
    print("Player1 win!!")
```

For the choices

```
player1 = 'rock'
player2 = 'scissor'
```

The conditions would evaluate as follows

```
(false and false) or (true and true) or (false or false)
```

Which is

```
false or true or false
true or false
true
```

Thus resulting the whole condition as true
Thus the output

```
Player 1 wins
```

As for the second input

```
player1 = 'scissor'
player2 = 'rock'
```

The condition evaluation goes as follows

```
(true and false) or (false and false) or (false and true)
false or false or true
false or true
true
```

Thus in any of the above cases, the first condition becomes true, thus resulting in the same result.
Just fix your last condition expression as

```
if player1!="" and player2!="":
if (player2=="rock" and player1=="paper") or (player2=="scissor" and player1=="rock") or (player2=="paper" and player1=="scissor"):
    print("Player1 win!!")
```

Similarly for the second condition

```
elif (player1=="rock" and player2=="paper") or (player1=="scissor" and player2=="rock") or (player1=="paper" and player2=="scissor"):
    print("Player2 win!!")
```

This will fix your problem.
I'd have written a one liner but you know, better answer on stack overflow requires a lengthy answer thus have to blab about the basics.